# Homotopy equivalent but not deformation retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Can somebody come up with an example where $X \subset Y$, the inclusion gives a homotopy equivalence between $X$ and $Y$, but there is no deformation retraction from $Y$ onto $X$?

Comment: Sure. Take the punctured plane and draw a circle to the right of the puncture. Then the inclusion map is not a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Right, so to make the question interesting you should ask for the inclusion to be a homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

There are known examples of spaces which are [contractible but do not deformation retract](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495856/showing-that-a-zigzag-space-is-contractible) onto any point in them. So you can take $Y$ to be such a space and $X$ to be any point in it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the space 
$$Y=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \exists m \in \mathbb Q\ y=mx \}$$
this space is contractible, so it is homotopy equivalent to the point $\{(1,0)\}=X$ for instance, nevertheless $\{(1,0)\}$ is not a deformation retract of $Y$.