# The inclusion map $V\subset U$ is nullhomotopic. - Is this proof legit?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification

There are many discussions has done on Hatcher 0.5, some [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294807/hatcher-ch-0-p18-5-inclusion-map-is-nullhomotopic), and some [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26190/showing-that-an-inclusion-is-null-homotopic). But I am primarily uncertain about the invoke of tube lemma. Wonder if someone would kind help me take a look at my proof and help me verify or revise? Thank you.

> Show that if a space $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x \in X$, then for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ there exists a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $x$ such that the inclusion map $V\subset U$ is nullhomotopic.

Given $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x \in X$, we know there is a family of maps $f_t: X \to X, t \in I$, such that $f_0 = \mathbb{I}$ (the identity map), $f_1(X) = x$, and $f_t|x=  \mathbb{I}$ for all $t$.

> **Tube Lemma**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces with $Y$ compact, and consider the product space $X \times Y$. If $N$ is an open set containing a slice in $X \times Y$, then there exists a tube in $X \times Y$ containing this slice and contained in $N$.

To make sure $f_t(V) \subset V$, we need to find the appropriate $V$. By the definition of retraction, we know that $f_t(x) = x$, that is the slice $x \times I$ is contained in some open set $N$, and hence by tube lemma, $N$ also contains a tube containing the slice $x \times I$. Hence, let $V = N$.

Now we consider the inclusion map $i: V \to U$, and consider another family of maps: $\tilde{f}_t = f_t \circ i: X \to X, t \in I$ such that $\tilde{f}_0 = \mathbb{I} \circ i = i, \tilde{f}_1 = c \circ i$, $\tilde{f}_t|c=  \mathbb{I}$ for all $t$.

Hence we constructed a homotopy map from inclusion map to a constant map, hence it is nullhomotopic.

Comment: What you have is a homotopy of maps $U \rightarrow X$ and what you're looking for is homotopy of maps $U \rightarrow V$. That is, you have a priori no control over whether $f_{t}(U) \subseteq V$ for all $t \in I$.